# yum get rid of "unfinished transactions remaining"

Tags: yum

```
yum xxx
...
There are unfinished transactions remaining. You might consider running yum-complete-transaction first to finish them.
```

I don't want to finish the transaction, how do I just nuke it?

Running `yum clean all` doesn't do it.  Running `yum-complete-transaction` and answering "N" to the prompt also no, it just said "Not removing old transaction files"

Answer (score 11, accepted):

This worked

```
 sudo yum-complete-transaction --cleanup-only
```

[from here](https://forums.fedoraforum.org/showthread.php?266324-How-can-I-get-rid-of-quot-unfinished-transaction-quot-warning)

Comment: works like a charm on CentOS 6.10 x86.

Comment: I get this error, but the command, even though it suggests it for me, does not seem to work on centos7 core

Answer (score 1):

On CentOS 7 you should first run:

```
yum install yum-utils
```

then run:

```
sudo yum-complete-transaction --cleanup-only
```

Comment: This is very similar to the other answer - it's probably better to edit that to say that `yum-utils` must be installed, rather than writing a new answer that's mostly duplicate.